# 5GHz Hotspot creation using ubuntu mate 18.04.3

Tags: hot-spot, ap-hotspot

Can you please help me in resolving my 5GHz hotspot creation issue?
my thread is here below

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2424872

please find the output of "iw list" command below

https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/V8Y4s939dT/

Comment: please paste the output of `iw list` to https://paste.ubuntu.com/ and edit you post adding the link to the paste -- `iw list` gives capabilities of the WiFi adapter

Comment: please find the output of "iw list" command below

https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/V8Y4s939dT/